# HtmlGenericControl vs Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create table from code-behind.
I can create either by using

```
HtmlGenericControl table = new HtmlGenericControl("table")
```

Or

```
Table table = new Table().
```

Either way I can create a table. But, in case of performance, which one is faster?

**Update:**
**For example:** The structure may like this. There may be more than one structure in a page.

[image]

**Note:** If there are other better solution it will be appreciated. Please avoid `javascript/jquery` as far as possilbe.

Comment: Do you have issues with your performance? Did you measure it and find out where the bottleneck is? I bet this question does not have any significant impact on your performance at all. To decide which one to use let other criteria lead you: What do you need to do with it? Which does most properly represent your intent? Etc.

Comment: <opinion>BTW. If you care about performance, stop using WebForms</opinion>

Comment: @chiccodoro Do you have some data/site/blog that have some kind of compare and prove your opinion ?

Comment: @chiccodoro: I just wanted to know before I start my task.

Comment: @Aristos. No, that's why it is just a comment and enclosed in <opinion> markers. But it is based on my own experience and the fact that a huge payload of data (viewstate) is passed back and forth between client and server on every event (postback). In the light of that payload, discussing on using one or the other control seems futile to me.

Comment: @chiccodoro I have some "bad" news for you, I work with WebForms and my sites and pages runs faster than any other, less than 50ms to show data, less than a second to fully load the page and run the scripts, query 50 tables for one page, with cache of course, and other tricks. So you have wrong, and in logic of Aristotelis, the one that claims something needs to be prove it, not the other one. So you need to prove your opinion (at least to your self). WebForms can be so fast that you can not imagine it.

Comment: @Aristos - I capitulate, I'm sure you're right. I know my comment was kind of silly. And yet my point that I tried to explain in my response does not necessarily change. How did you manage to make your application that fast? Did you reduce the view state load? You mentioned caching, too. But did you wrack your brain about picking between `Table` or `HtmlGenericControl`?

Comment: @chiccodoro: In my case I have to export the structure which I'm doing using tables. Since I need to create dynamic structure I'm working through code behind. That's my issue. So I was analyzing whether to use 'HtmlGenericControl' or 'Table'.

Comment: @Aristos: Thank you for the support. But I need to know- which one is better to use 'HtmlGenericControl' or 'Table'?

Comment: @sna2stha - as I said: Take the one that fits your needs. Don't wrack your brain about performance. (That is, *do* wrack your brain about performance, but don't do it in this very question.)

Comment: @sna2stha Both of them are (almost) equal, you can not notice any difference. You can also direct render a table to a string, and place it on page. The bottleneck is hidden on different code, eg on the database access, on the full page struct...

Comment: @Aristos: Thank you aristos. Now I can go with my task. Thank you very much.

Comment: @sna2stha To make your page very fast, you first make them, then you see if they are slow, and where, and after long time you start the optimizations. Beside optimizations cache is the key for a faster web site. Cache on many points, even cache the full page, or partial of the page, cache on database returns, cache on resources... etc. And by the time you get some experience and you make some earlier optimizations.... load part of the page with ajax... many tricks that you can find them on internet.